# Is there a way to remove Jupyter "Run Cell" buttons in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to remove the Jupyter "Run Cell|Run All Cells" buttons that appear if the syntax `#%%` is present in Visual Studio Code.

[image: vsc]

Is there a setting that controls that?

Answer (score 11):

You can toggle off `Python>Data Science: Enable Cell Code Lens` settings.

[image: Screenshot from settings]

Comment: Just to add, this disables the "Go to <output>" cell lens, and there doesn't seem to be any command that would provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn off the data science features (the Python Interactive window) under Settings>Python>Data Science>Enabled then you won't see those code lenses any more. However that will also hide the rest of the data science features along with the lenses. Were you looking to turn off all data science features in the python extension or just the lenses?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was looking to turn just the lenses (if that is what is it called). Just the 'Run Cell | Run All Cells' emblem.

Comment: Sorry Domen, there isn't currently a way to turn off just the lenses. If you want you could file an issue here on our GitHub:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues. Personally that seems like it could be a reasonable option for folks who don't want the visual clutter in their files.

Comment: There used to be a way to do this... now I cannot find it. I'm not seeing the Settings>Python Data Science features you're talking about, can you elaborate?

Comment: Found it! `"jupyter.enableCellCodeLens": false`

Answer (score 2):

Update for others coming to this question:

With recent update you can choose what's displayed `Run cell` |...".
If you're looking to remove clutter delete everything and save like below:

[image]

I would recommend leaving at least `python.datascience.runcell` as it seems to disable shift+enter shortcut

Comment: Disabling the lenses seems to disable the commands as well. What the heck is that about?

Answer (score -2):

Save the code snippet below as : *`remove_inline_comment.py`*
Assuming your filename as : *`sample_file.py`*,
RUN : python remove_inline_comment.py sample_file.py

[ NOTE : Make sure both of these files are in same folder ]

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
import re


def process(filename):
    """Removes empty lines and lines that contain only whitespace, and
    lines with comments"""

    with open(filename) as in_file, open(filename, "r+") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if re.match("# In\[[0-9\\d+\]]", line):
                out_file.write("\n")
            else:
                out_file.writelines(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Removing the In#\[[0-9\d+\]] in notebook to script conversion"
    )

    my_parser.add_argument(
        "script_path",
        metavar="path",
        type=str,
        help="path to script that requires a conversion",
    )

    args = my_parser.parse_args()
    script_path = args.script_path

    file_format = script_path.split(".")[1]
    if file_format != "py":
        print("File is not a py file")
        sys.exit()

    try:
        print(f"processing : {script_path}")
        process(script_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Please provide path correctly")
```